# Is there a way to get my newly installed Python 3 to recognize all of the libraries I had installed when I was using Python 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running an AWS environment (Amazon Linux) and trying to run a Python3 script that needs a ton of libraries.  I spent a super long time figuring out how to install them all, only to realize that I was running Python 2 and Python 3 was not installed.

So I installed Python 3:

```
sudo yum install python36
```

but then I tried to run my script, and it doesn't recognize any of my libraries.  I don't want to and don't know how to to reinstall Python 3 versions of everything.  Is there any way to get Python 3 to recognize all of my libraries?  I am certain that they are all compatible with Python 3.  We're talking things like Tensorflow, Keras, Scipy, etc.

Comment: How sure are you that they're compatible? http://python-future.org/translation.html

Comment: If you use the latest AMI 2017-09, you will get installed Python3 inside EC2 and reinstall all your module compariable with python 3. I guess no way to use module of python2 in python3 completely

Comment: No I'm not sure.  How do I check?  The first one it errors out on is called "tqdm."  (I'm running something someone else wrote)

Comment: +BTuan:  I am using AMI 2017-09, but when I did the command "python3" it said I didn't have it (which I thought was very strange), so I installed it myself.  Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: [AMI 2017-09](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/aws/now-available-amazon-linux-ami-2017-09/). Sorry, not installed but support to install with command `sudo yum install python36 python36-virtualenv python36-pip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably not work, for either Python code or C extension modules, because the Python 3 API for C extension modules is not backward-compatible with Python 2, and the Python 3 language has also changed in some backward-incompatible ways. So you will need new versions of all libraries.

Comment: How do I install them? The installers (I assume) default to installing for Python 2.

Comment: Did you install these from standard packages for the Linux distro? There should be alternative versions of the packages. For example, for scipy on my Debian system, `python-scipy` is the package for Python 2, while the one for Python 3 is called `python3-scipy`.

Comment: On the AWS environment I installed the first library:
    pip install tqdm
When I do this on my machine, and run the code with Python 3 (which I installed with Anaconda), it just works.  However, in the Amazon environment, Python 3 doesn't find the library.  It seems to me that it is not about the library version, but that Python 3 does not know where to look for the library.

Comment: Use standard Linux packages where available. But if you must use `pip`, then try the `pip3` command instead.